# Backup Database (SQL 2000 Compatibility) on SQL Server 2005 with CHECKSUM, but Page Verification TORN_PAGES Detection

Tags: windows-server, backup, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I am trying to backup a 250GB database on SQL Server 2005 running in SQL 2000 compatibility mode.

The page verification is set to TORN_PAGES detection.
So, far the backup has been corrupted when we try to copy the backup to an external and restore on a different server.

The error I got in the past was as follows:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE detected an error on page (0:0) in database "MMS.mdf" as read from the backup set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

If I perform a backup with CHECKSUM enabled in the backup options, then does it look like the restore will work on the other server or is the database itself corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file permissions on the backup on the second server.  It's possible that's your problem, and it's easily fixed.

If that doesn't fix it, you should run a `dbcc checkdb` on the original database, which will tell you if the database itself is corrupt.

If DBCC returns okay, run a `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'path to backup'` on the backup on the original server.

If all of that returns okay, go back to the second server and double-check the file permissions.

Comment: Thanks, can you please expand on what you mean by check file permissions? I'm not a DBA or sysadmin, but do you mean to see if the file is readonly?

Comment: I mean make sure that SQL Server can read it.  I'm talking about the NTFS permissions.  Whatever account SQL Server runs as has to be able to read the file.